# Android sqlite select withour duplicate ids

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know is there any way that I can remove duplicates from my select statement in it's own code.

Example :

I have :

`SELECT gl.genre_id , gl.title FROM genre_lang AS gl LEFT JOIN genres AS g ON (gl.genre_id=g.genre_id) WHERE ( gl.lang_code='es_ES' OR gl.lang_code='en_US') ORDER BY gl.title`

and my result is something like this :

```
1      Movies
2      Sport
3      Theathre
3      Drbrbrbr (it should be theathre in spanish)
5      Music
```

and etc. and the thing that I want to achieve is to show `Theathre` only in english/spanish?

Is there any way that I can achieve this using sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `DISTINCT` in your query to select non repetitive records only.

```
SELECT gl.genre_id , gl.title FROM genre_lang AS gl LEFT JOIN genres AS g ON 
(gl.genre_id=g.genre_id) WHERE ( gl.lang_code='es_ES' OR gl.lang_code='en_US' 
AND gl.genre_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT gl.genre_id FROM genre_lang)) 
ORDER BY gl.title
```

Comment: actually i had tried this before and it was not working..but after making some changes it's now working properly...so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT distinct gl.genre_id , gl.title FROM genre_lang AS gl LEFT JOIN genres AS g ON (gl.genre_id=g.genre_id) WHERE ( gl.lang_code='es_ES' OR gl.lang_code='en_US') ORDER BY gl.title`